# Conjugate momentum in the vacuum functional for the fermionic oscillator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral, fermions

The vacuum functional for the fermionic oscillator is given by

$$
Z[0] = N\int\mathcal{D}\overline{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi \exp\left(i\int_0^Tdt\left(i\overline{\psi}\psi-w\overline{\psi}\psi  \right)\right).
\tag{5.80}$$

Using Weyl ordering and discretizing the time integral, it is [claimed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812568476) that this could be written as

$$
Z[0] = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}N\int d\overline{\psi}_1\dots d\overline{\psi}_{N-1}d\psi_1\dots d\psi_{N-1}$$
$$\times \exp\left(i\epsilon\sum_{n=1}^N\left(i\overline{\psi}_n\frac{\psi_n-\psi_{n-1}}{\epsilon}-w\overline{\psi}_n\frac{\psi_n+\psi_{n-1}}{2}  \right)\right),\tag{5.81}
$$

where the mid-point prescription of the Weyl ordering was used.

My question is pretty simple and naive. To write this expression, the author says on the bottom of p.92 that

> $\overline{\psi}$ represents the momentum conjugate to $\psi$.

But if I make the computation I get (using left derivatives)

$$
\Pi_\psi = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\psi}}=-i\overline{\psi}.\tag{5.43}
$$

Why is it valid to ignore the $-i$ factor and just to consider $\overline{\psi}$ as the conjugate momentum?

Comment: ${}$ Which page?

Comment: p92, second edition. Thanks for looking it up!

Comment: Does it make you equation for $Z[0]$ invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Ashok Das is not ignoring any factor of $-i$ in formulas. The word *"represent"* in the sentence *$\overline{\psi}$ represents the conjugate to $\psi$* is here used semantically in a weaker sense than *"is equal",* e.g. *"is equal up to a multiplicative constant".*

Comment: General question. What is then the rule in order to apply the mid-point prescription? It seems to me that this is a loosely rule, and I'm worried that different cases yield different answers. Does this only happens for fermions?